# Configuration jobs "Jenkins"

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

i use Jenkins as a continuous integration server.
i try to configure a job that it will execute automatically after the launch of the execution of another job. If possible, is what labs time is configurable? there is a way ??

Answer (score 0):

There is a section on the job configuration called `Build Triggers` with an option `Build after other projects are built`. I guess that's what you want to configure on your initial job.

Comment: i don't need to run a job after an other one, i just need to run each other together with a small time difference when launching